# How to index specific object in dataloader without enumeration

Tags: python, dataset, pytorch

I have the following code for testing a network in pytorch (taken from [pix2pix](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/master/test.py)):

```
for i, data in enumerate(dataset):
    model.set_input(data)
    model.test()
```

I have tried altering this to access only one element (any) over iterating a number of elements. the following:

```
data=dataset[0]
```

leads to

> TypeError: 'CustomDatasetDataLoader' object does not support indexing

where `CustomDatasetDataLoader` is a [custom class by the author](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/master/data/__init__.py) which (if I am understanding correctly) herniates from [torch.utils.data.DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html).

I am fairly new to python, how do I index a single specific element of `dataset` if it is at all possible?

Comment: Did you found how to do this ?

Comment: @Walter I did not and I left it because I went in another direction. at a second glance though, try `torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, indices)`https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html() and kindly update is it works.

Comment: Isn't it just dataset.__getitem__(0)?